# JavaScript syntax highlighting in Aptana

Tags: javascript, aptana, syntax-highlighting

I am using Aptana for my wen development project. I am wondering if there is any ways in Aptana so that the identical syntax (ie. variable names) in my script file can all be highlighted.

For example:

```
function(storeItem, item) {

                var total = 0;
                store.each(function(rec) {
                    total += rec.get('data1');
                }) ;
                this.setTitle(storeItem.get('name') + ': ' + Math.round(storeItem.get('data1') / total * 100) + '%');


        }
```

If I select `storeItem` variable, then all the variable named `storeItem` will be highlighted. Is that possible in Aptana?

Or you can suggest another IDE which have that function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) will highlight matching occurences. It's not quite an IDE, but has a healthy list of plugins.

IIRC, [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) also does this, but isn't what you might call an IDE.

Comment: Thanks, but I am using WebStorm now. which has much better build-in code hinting module. Aptana just costs me so long to find the right plugin to support code assist.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want the option Window/Preferences/Pydev/Editor/Mark Occurrences. Not exactly obvious. Ironically, I found it looking for a way to turn it off. Full disclosure: I'm doing python development atm, so I can't verify whether it works for JS.

The "Mark Occurrences" option seems to exist for all the editors. Just go to Preferences >> Aptana Studios >> Editors >> JavaScript.